# Failed to bind properties clientid to OAuth2ClientProperties$Registration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on a spring boot app in order to communicate with another secured API.
For that, I implement a OAuth2RestTemplate with the following properties but it failed when I run the application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("oauth2")
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
        return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(
            @Qualifier("oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails") OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails);
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
            clientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            accessTokenUri: https://xxxxxx/oauth2/access_token
            scope: openid profile xxxxxxxxxxx
            authorizationGrantType: client_credentials
```

The exception I get when I run the code

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.clientid' to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientProperties$Registration:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          mb:
            client-name: mb
            client-id: ui
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http:localhost:8084/ui/login/oauth2/code/
            scope: openId
            client-authentication-method: basic
        provider:
          mb:
            token-uri: http://localhost:8181/oauth/token
            authorization-uri: http:localhost:8181/oauth/authorize
            user-info-uri: http:localhost:8181/oauth/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: name
```

Comment: here? what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Please, provide an explanation. Such a short answer is not a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-sample-application-config) mentions that you need to provide a `registrationId` within the property "path"

You application.properties should look like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          YOUR_REGISTRATION_ID: # <----------
            clientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            accessTokenUri: https://xxxxxx/oauth2/access_token
            scope: openid profile xxxxxxxxxxx
            authorizationGrantType: client_credentials
```